# Electron-Hole Spin Exchange Interaction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, semiconductor-physics, hamiltonian, many-body

I am stuck with this seemingly "simple" Hamiltonian. I am dealing with an exchange term of a Hamiltonian for two different spin species:

$$H_\text{exchange} = - \lambda J \cdot S = -\sum_{i=x,y,z}\lambda J_i S_i \, ,$$
where the $J_i$ are $4\times 4$ Pauli matrices for spin $3/2$, and the $S_i$ are $2\times2$ matrices for spin $1/2$ systems.

As the Pauli matrices are of different sizes, how do I expand the Hamiltonian? I believe the operation needs to be done in a larger Hilbert space so the Pauli matrices need to be expanded. How exactly would I proceed? Any reference, suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You need to perform tensor product of the matrices. By doing this you will get the matrix with the dimension 4x2=8. The similar tensor product you should perform with the wavefunctions, so they span 8 dimensional space. Your new wavefunction will be a vector in this new basis.